# SpringMVC - JSP Iteration Issue

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, input

I have the following class that I am attempting to use as a command object

```
public class Member {

   private String datePeriod;
   private String status;
   private ArrayList <Project> projectList;

}
```

On the JSP, I would like the form to prefill with a pre-existing values.

```
<c:forEach items="${member.projectList}" var="project">            

  <tr>       
    <td><form:input path="**<var???>**" value="${project.projectEntry.projectDesc}" /></td>                       
  </tr>

</c:forEach>
```

I am making an error with path which is causing an error in jsp. Does anyone know the proper syntax with regards to each iteration? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My Spring MVC is bit rusty but if I remember correctly, path gets translated as the input name property in HTML eventually. So you can put any Label value in there and that should work.

`<form:input path="ProjectDescription" value="${project.projectEntry.projectDesc}" type="text" />`

This should get translated to:

`<input name="ProjectDescription" type="text" value="<whatever_you_have_in_backing_bean>"/>`

Do you want to look up name from a backing bean instead? If so you should be able to do something like below. Without knowing your data structure I am assuming it to be status.

`<form:input path="member.status" value="${project.projectEntry.projectDesc}" type="text" />`

More on the form tag [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-formtaglib-formtag).